# Codeigniter thumbnail image path can not be stored in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, image-uploading, gd2

I am trying to make a simple app with Codeigniter where i need to store thumbnail image path in MySql database. The images along with the thumbnail versions upload correctly in the upload folder and  I can store the image path in my database while uploading but i can not store the thumbnail image path in the database. I tried this in the controller:

```
$thumbnail= $this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], $data['upload_data']  ['file_name']);
$thumbnail_path = './uploads/'. $thumbnail;
$newRow = array(
                    "title" => $this->input->post('title'),
                    "img_path" => $imgpath,
                    "thumbnail_path" => $thumbnail_path,
                    "post_body" => $this->input->post('post_body')
                    )
```

But it only stores  "./uploads/" in the thumbnail_path column in my table, not  the actual thumbnail path. Where i expect it to store  something like "./uploads/Lighthouse_thumb.jpg". I can not figure out how to get the path of the thumbnail images to store them in the database. Here is my full upload controller:

```
  class Upload extends CI_Controller
  {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');    
}
function index() {

        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error'=>''));
    }

function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else {
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $imgpath = './uploads/' . $image_data['file_name'];
        $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
        $thumbnail= $this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], $data['upload_data']['file_name']);
        $thumbnail_path = './uploads/'. $thumbnail;
        $newRow = array(
                    "title" => $this->input->post('title'),
                    "img_path" => $imgpath,
                    "thumbnail_path" => $thumbnail_path,
                    "post_body" => $this->input->post('post_body')
                    );
            $this->load->model('postimage_path');
            $this->postimage_path->insert($newRow);
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }

    }
function resize($path, $file) {
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] =  $path;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintian_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 100;
        $config['height'] = 100;
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/' . $file;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$thumbnail_path = './uploads/'. $thumbnail;
```

So `thumbnail_path` contains only "./uploads/" : that tells us that `$thumbnail` is false (or null or empty string etc.), meaning that the return value of the call to resize is wrong - it seems you expect it to return the file name.

```
function resize($path, $file) {
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] =  $path;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintian_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 100;
    $config['height'] = 100;
    $config['new_image'] = './uploads/' . $file;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

}
```

`resize` returns nothing! And you assign that nothing to `$thumbnail_path`. That's your problem.

You seem to have simply copied the code from [the CodeIgniter docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html). From said docs (emphasis mine):

> The above code tells the image_resize function to look for an image called mypic.jpg located in the source_image folder, then create a thumbnail that is 75 X 50 pixels using the GD2 image_library. Since the maintain_ratio option is enabled, the thumb will be as close to the target width and height as possible while preserving the original aspect ratio. **The thumbnail will be called mypic_thumb.jpg**

So there you have it! If your filename is `$data['upload_data']['file_name']`, your thumbnail will be `$data['upload_data']['file_name'] . "_thumb"`. Have a look at your file system, the files should be there for you to see.

So to fix your problem, this should do the trick:

```
 $pathinfo = pathinfo($data['upload_data']['file_name']);
 $thumbnail_path = './uploads/'. $data['upload_data']['file_name'] . "_thumb" . $pathinfo['extension'];
```

Comment: How i can grab the path of the newly created thumb versions of the images from resize function. How i can make it return the path? is there any way? i have tried your way. it tries to insert in the db something like this. [INSERT INTO `post` (`title`, `img_path`, `thumbnail_path`, `post_body`) VALUES ('Hello world', './uploads/Tulips.jpg', './uploads/Tulips.jpg_thumbjpg', 'I love php')].

Comment: I have checked. See the thumb version image path is wrong. Because the resize funcntion created the thumb as "Tulips_thumb.jpg" , but its storing something else. May be with some experiment i can store the path of the thumb versions not from the resize function but with pathinfo function. I got some hints though. I am working on it. Any further help from you will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: and yes i have been able to store the path of the thumbnail images in the db with slight modification of your way. I have used this:  $thumbnail_path = './uploads/'. $data['upload_data']['raw_name'] . "_thumb" . "." . $pathinfo['extension'];   Now it can successfully store the actual path of the thumbnails. Thank you again. Stay blessed!